# input type button as ActionLink in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to use input type button as ActionLink in MVC?

I used javascript to trigger the right action as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ButtonClick(Action) {
            document.location(Action);
        }
    </script>

<input type="button" value="CLICK ME" onclick="ButtonClick('MyAction')" />
```

I am sure there is some better and straight way to accomplish this. Can any one help?

Comment: you can make link look like button using css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make link look like button using css:

### Razor

`@Html.ActionLink("Link As Button","Action",null,new {@class= "LinkButton"}`)

### HTML

```
<a class="LinkButton" href="/Action">Link As Button</a>
```

### CSS

```
.LinkButton {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8VLvS/)

Comment: Thanks Ehsan , This will do what i want to achieve. But was wondering if there is a way to do other way?

Comment: Other way then is to use input type submit and form post? But I think this one is more better

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Signup" class="btn btn-default btn-block" />
```

You should put this action link under a form tag.

Comment: i tried to write that code , but it shows nothing. Thats why i gave image :(